# Requesting Refuah Sheleimah for Oneself

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, choleh-sick

Is one allowed to request a refuah sheleimah (a speedy recovery) for oneself, while saying Shemona Esreh? If so, does one need to say one’s Hebrew name, or just say אותי ("me")?

Comment: 1. Gemmorah says one asks for others BEFORE asking for himself, therefore personal requests are permitted (even intended, I'd say) 2. Moses said "רפא נא לה" refering to Miriam, so G-d knows who's he davens about, same with "me"

Answer (score 3):

Well this is exactly the content of the [Refaeinu blessing](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Amidah%2C_Healing?lang=bi)

> וְהַעֲלֵה רְפוּאָה שְׁלֵמָה לְכָל מַכּותֵינוּ 
>  Bring complete
>   healing to all our wounds

So you seem to be covered for yourself. If you wish to add the standard *yehi ratzon* addition, you can do as well: OU [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/tefillah/shemoneh-esrei/shemoneh_esrei_8/) says

> If one wishes to ask special consideration from God **for oneself** or
>   another who is ill, he may insert a personal request here. (Many
>   siddurim offer a suggested text for such insertions.)

The Mishna Brura ([SA OC 116:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.116.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.116.3&lang2=bi)) writes not to say the name of the sick person if one is in front of him or her. I presume this would apply to oneself.

As always, [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before applying anything you read here.

Comment: B"H for this answer. I have a headache from reading it :-8 Refuah Shleima to me! Hey, it seems to work quickly. Another B"H!